# WPF what is the event before rendering

Tags: c#, wpf

I create a simple game in WPF application and I want to change objects in the window before it render them.
What is my best option? :)

Comment: Use Window `Loaded` event.

Comment: @RohitVats the Loaded event happens before or after the the window is rendered?

Comment: `Loaded` event raise first and then `ContentRendered` event is raised when actual content gets rendered on Window.

Answer (score 14):

Following events are fired before the content is rendered in WPF :

1. Startup (Application)
2. Initialized (Window)
3. SourceInitialized (Window)
4. Activated (Application)
5. Activated (Window)
6. Loaded (Window)

Loaded is the last event fired before the contents are rendered and you can use it to make changes to the objects.

Read this article to know more : [Lifetime Events of a WPF application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/403418/Lifetime-events-of-a-WPF-application)